# Unavailable cache in console controller

Tags: caching, yii2, apc

I have a two Yii2 controllers: web and console.
Cache component configured via APC

In web-action:

```
public function actionIndex() {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->cache->get('rbac')); // returns normal array
}
```

In console-action:

```
public function actionInit() {
        var_dump(Yii::$app->cache->get('rbac'));// returns false
}
```

APC is enabled for CLI in config (apc.enable_cli=1 in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini).

How to get cache in console app?

Comment: read this [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-console-controllers-cachecontroller.html)